# How to print a triangle of Binary numbers in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to add binary number logic into this snippet. I just cannot wrap my head around how to implement binary numbers, I could just add `0`s and `1`s but that does not seem to be right

```
namespace Star_Pyramid
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num;
        Console.WriteLine("enter level");
        num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int count = 1;

        for (int lines = num; lines >= 1; lines--)
        {

            for (int spaces = lines - 1; spaces >= 1; spaces--)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");

            }
            for (int star = 1; star <= count; star++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                Console.Write(" ");

            }
            count++;

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "add binary number logic"

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i need to print a triangle that is made up of binary numbers

Comment: @MohammadQasim The first inner `for` can be replaced by `Console.Write(new String(' ', lines - 1));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [**modulo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%`)

```
  c = star % 2;        // will print first the '1'
  c = (star + 1) % 2;  // will print first the '0'
```

---

```
    int num;
    Console.WriteLine("enter level");
    num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int count = 1;
    int c = 0;

    for (int lines = num; lines >= 1; lines--)
    {

        for (int spaces = lines - 1; spaces >= 1; spaces--)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");

        }
        for (int star = 1; star <= count; star++)
        {
            c = star % 2; //this will return 1 if the value of star is odd then 0 if even
            Console.Write(c);
            Console.Write(" ");

        }
        count++;

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

**[VIEW DEMO](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=35430)**

Comment: on the line mentioned above, what does 0:1; mean?

Comment: to alternate the printing of 1 and 0.. try to view the demo

Comment: oh i get it. So 0:1; is kinda like Console.Write("0") and Console.Write("1"); ?

Comment: @MohammadQasim, No,  `star % 2 == 0? 0:1;` is a shorthand of `if-else` it's the same as `if(star % 2 == 0?){ c = 0;} else { c=1;}`

Comment: @MohammadQasim `?` and `:` is a conditional assignment. Before the `?` you see the condition. After the `?` you see the value that will be assigned when the condition is true, after the `:` you see the value that will be assigned when the condition is false. In this example `star % 2 == 0` is the condition and the result `0` or `1` will be assigned to `c`.

Comment: %2 will already return 1 or 0 without the ternary operator (statement ? true :false thingy)

Comment: @modiX call me crazy but i never knew that. :(

Comment: @MohammadQasim, i edited my answer no need to use the if else, modulo will return 1 if odd and 0 if even

Comment: @DyrandzFamador thanks for that. But that earlier technique you used was really useful :)